# Pydantic - apply validator on all fields of specific type

Tags: python, validation, pydantic, code-duplication

In my project, all `pydantic` models inherit from a custom "base model" called `GeneralModel`.

This enables to configure the same behavior for the entire project in one place.

Let's assume the following implementation:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class GeneralModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        use_enum_values = True
        exclude_none = True
```

One particularly desired behavior is to perform a validation on all fields of a specific type.

Any ideas how to achieve this using my `GeneralModel`? Different approaches are blessed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the Pydantic [validators documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/):

> a single validator can also be called on all fields by passing the special value `'*'`

and:

> you can also add any subset of the following arguments to the signature (the names **must** match):
>
> [...]
>
> - `field`: the field being validated. Type of object is `pydantic.fields.ModelField`.

So you can write a catch-all validator and pass it the `ModleField` instance as an argument. Then check the type of the field and apply whatever validation you want.

Very simple example:

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from pydantic.fields import ModelField


class GeneralModel(BaseModel):
    @validator("*")
    def ensure_non_negative(cls, v: Any, field: ModelField) -> Any:
        if field.type_ is float and v < 0:
            raise ValueError(f"`{field.name}` value must not be negative")
        return v

    class Config:
        ...
```

Usage:

```py
from pydantic import ValidationError

# ... import GeneralModel


class ConcreteModel(GeneralModel):
    x: float
    y: str = "foo"


print(ConcreteModel(x=3.14))
try:
    ConcreteModel(x=-1)
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```
x=3.14 y='foo'
```

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "x"
        ],
        "msg": "`x` value must not be negative",
        "type": "value_error"
    }
]
```

**Note:** When defining a field as for example `list[str]`, Pydantic internally considers the field **type** to be `str`, but its **shape** to be `pydantic.fields.SHAPE_LIST`. Luckily, `shape` is also a public attribute of `ModelField`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75842318) for an example, where this is important.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to use [Annotated Validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#annotated-validators)

Then you can perform a validation on the specific type as you request

> on all fields of a specific type

So in your case it would be something like this

```py
def my_validator(v: Any) -> Any:
    assert v > 0, f'{v} should not be negative'
    return v


MyFloat = Annotated[float, AfterValidator(my_validator)]


class ConcreteModel(GeneralModel):
    x: MyFloat
    y: str = "foo"
```